# "Invalid property assignment:.. read-only property" in Qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm attempting to use a list property in Qml for an underlying C++ object. I would like to be able to read and write it. The documentation for QQmlListProperty says that only the READ function is implemented, and is used for reading *and* writing the object. I get the error message:

> Invalid property assignment: "string" is a read-only property

when I try to run the app. Here are the relevant source files:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<A>("TestQmlComponents", 1, 0, "A");

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/TestQml/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import TestQmlComponents 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    A {
        id: a
        string: [
            "a", "b", "c"
        ]
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <QString>
#include <QtQml/QQmlListProperty>

class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<QString> string READ stringList)

public:
    explicit A(QObject *parent = 0);

    static void addString(QQmlListProperty<QString> *list, QString *str);
    void addString(QString *str);
    static int stringCount(QQmlListProperty<QString> *list);
    int stringCount() const;
    QQmlListProperty<QString> stringList();
    static QString *getString(QQmlListProperty<QString> *list, int ix);
    QString *getString(int ix);

private:
    QList<QString *> _string;
};

#endif // A_H
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

A::A(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void A::addString(QQmlListProperty<QString> *list, QString *str)
{
    A *obj = qobject_cast<A *>(list->object);

    if (obj)
       obj->addString(str);
}

void A::addString(QString *str)
{
    _string << str;
}

int A::stringCount(QQmlListProperty<QString> *list)
{
    A *obj = qobject_cast<A *>(list->object);

    if (obj)
        return obj->stringCount();

    return 0;
}

QString *A::getString(int ix)
{
    return _string.at(ix);
}

QString *A::getString(QQmlListProperty<QString> *list, int ix)
{
    A *obj = qobject_cast<A *>(list->object);

    if (obj)
        return obj->getString(ix);

    return NULL;
}

int A::stringCount() const
{
    return _string.count();
}

QQmlListProperty<QString> A::stringList()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<QString>(this, NULL, addString, stringCount, getString, NULL);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QQmlListProperty` can only be used for lists of QObject-derived object pointers.

Since a [`QStringList`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#sequence-type-to-javascript-array) is transparently exposed to JavaScript as an array type, you can expose such a property directly in two ways:

1. As a `Q_PROPERTY`, with the caveat that modifications are expensive, since the entire string list is retrieved, then modified, then written back. For large lists this is slow.

   ```
   Q_PROPERTY(QStringList strings READ strings WRITE setStrings NOTIFY stringsChanged)
   Q_SIGNAL void stringsChanged(const QStringList &);
   ...
   QStringList strings() const { return m_strings; }
   void setStrings(const QStringList & strings ) {
     m_strings = strings;
     emit stringsChanged(m_strings);
   }
   ```
2. As a reference returned from a `Q_INVOKABLE` method: the data is accessed directly.

   ```
   Q_INVOKABLE QStringList & strings() { return m_strings; }
   ```

Comment: Is it the case that, for QQmlListProperty, I need to have a setter? I knew that QDeclarativeListProperty had the restriction that the list could not be written except as a whole, but the documentation for QQmlListProperty indicated that this restriction had been lifted: "The QQmlListProperty encapsulates a group of function pointers that represet the set of actions QML can perform on the list - adding items, retrieving items and clearing the list." So the essential question is, how do I enable QML to add an item to a QQmlListProperty, as the documentation says I ought to be able to do?

Comment: @ScottDeerwester As I've said in the first line of the answer: you can't use a `QQmlListProperty` with a non-QObject class. That's your problem. You use it with a QString, and it won't ever work. Your `addString` "setter" is correct, you simply use the `QQmlListProperty` with a class that it can't be used with.

Comment: All right, I'm using QStringList for QStrings. Hopefully I'll be able to get other lists of QObject subclass pointers working with QQmlListProperty.